# Thumbnail Image to go in the post aswell

Tags: posts, images, single

I have looked everywhere but I cant see any clear answers, a lot about getting a thumbnail image. But I am after having the thumbnail which was uploaded to the post to also be in the post just made.

So it automatically puts the image in the post (top left corner for example)

Thank you

Comment: Why not just display the post thumbnail on the single.php template? This way the layout always stays perfect.

Comment: @Pippin you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the post thumbnail for the single blog pages too. You can use the add_image_size() function to create an additional image size that is displayed on the blog posts.

```
add_image_size('single-post-image', 650, 250, true); // name, width, height, crop mode
```

Then in single.php

```
the_post_thumbnail('image-size');
```

Simply place the first function in your functions.php, and the second in single.php. You can then wrap it with whatever you want to control the formatting. This way your formatting will always be perfect and you don't have to worry about sizing images exactly: they're all done for you.